# Spring AMQP XML Message Converter

Tags: spring-amqp

I'm trying to read a message from RabbitMQ using spring-amqp and convert it to my domain object.

I've successfully configured it to receive a json message and map it to my domain object using the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` class.

Now, I'm trying to use the `ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter` and add the ability to receive XML (in addition to JSON).

But, unfortunately, I'm having a hard time finding either a built-in message converter that handles XML or documentation on how to configure one of the built-in converters to handle XML.

The documentation on how to handle XML using spring-amqp seems pretty sparse. So, I'd appreciate a code sample that adds to mine below (please see *TODO*):

```
@Bean
MessageConverter messageConverter() {
  ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter messageConverter = new ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter();

  Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
  messageConverter.addDelegate("application/json", jsonMessageConverter);

  // TODO: messageConverter.addDelegate("application/xml", xxx);

  return messageConverter;
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [MarshallingMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#_marshallingmessageconverter) configured with a Spring OXM marshaller/unmarshaller - see [Spring Framework OXM documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#oxm) for information about the various marshallers/unmarshallers using a number of different technologies.